# Perl HTTP::Cookie add multiple cookies

Tags: perl, cookies, www-mechanize

I have written a Perl Script to send an HTTP GET request to a website. In the request headers, I want to set multiple cookies, so that the header looks like

```
Cookie: key1 = val1; key2 = val2; key3 = val3
```

I am using [`HTTP::Cookies`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP::Cookies) to set the cookies in a [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/module/WWW::Mechanize) object.

However `set_cookie()` can only add one cookie to the cookie jar. How can I add multiple cookies?

If I call the `set_cookie()` method multiple times, only the last cookie set in the cookie_jar is sent in the HTTP GET request.

Below is the code I have written

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use HTTP::Cookies;

$cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new();

$cookies->set_cookie(0, 'key1', 'val1', '/', 'domain', 80, 0, 0, 86400, 0);
$cookies->set_cookie(0, 'key2', 'val2', '/', 'domain', 80, 0, 0, 86400, 0);
$cookies->set_cookie(0, 'key3', 'val3', '/', 'domain', 80, 0, 0, 86400, 0);

$mech=WWW::Mechanize->new(cookie_jar => $cookies, timeout => 20);
$mech->agent_alias('Windows IE 6');

$url = "http://domain/path";

eval{$mech->get($url)};

if ($@) {
    print "there was an error in sending the HTTP GET request";
}

print $mech->content();
```

Below is how the HTTP GET request looks like:

```
GET /path HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: domain
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Cookie: key3=val3
Cookie2: $Version="1"
```

As you can see, in the HTTP GET request headers above, only the last cookie `key3` is sent. How can I send multiple cookies?

Comment: Did you try using a cookie jar file? 
$cookie_jar = HTTP::Cookies->new(
    file => "$ENV{'HOME'}/lwp_cookies.dat",
    autosave => 1,
);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work fine.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $jar = HTTP::Cookies->new({});
$jar->set_cookie(0, 'key1', 'val1', '/', 'example.com', 80, 0, 0, 86400, 0);
$jar->set_cookie(0, 'key2', 'val2', '/', 'example.com', 80, 0, 0, 86400, 0);
$jar->set_cookie(0, 'key3', 'val3', '/', 'example.com', 80, 0, 0, 86400, 0);

my $request = HTTP::Request->new( qw{ GET http://www.example.com/ } );
$jar->add_cookie_header($request);

print $request->as_string, "\n";
```

**output**

```
GET http://www.example.com/
Cookie: key2=val2; key1=val1; key3=val3
Cookie2: $Version="1"
```

Comment: Thanks. I got it working with WWW::Mechanize as well. The reason it was not working was because I was setting the domain field in set_cookie starting with a dot. For instance, .domain instead of domain. set_cookie will not add the cookie if the domain name field of cookie starts with a dot.